# I want to see all ids those are login from my android mobile

Tags: android, facebook

I want to see all ids those are login from my android mobile

as I can see from my browser.

Comment: Do you want to be a hacker?

Comment: I need to see whose id login from my mobile

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Facebook does not have a public API for returning the places of where the user is currently logged in.

If you are using the Android SDK, check the [reference docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current).

If you are using the Graph API, you can [see the docs here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

I think Facebook could not permit this due to security issues.